# How to make a method for searching from array and print entire arraybox?

Tags: java, arrays, file, search

I could use some help with a part of a code I am working on. 
I made a method which I think transformed every line of my .txt file into separate elements in an Array. However, I now want to be able to search in them and make the program print the entire element. ie: one of the lines reads: Crow, M, Kansas, june2012
I think I was able to make it into an array. Now I want to be able to search for "crow" and be able to get all the elements with that word in them printed alongside the rest of the String in the element.
The code I have so far:
     System.out.println("Her kan du soke etter registrerigner etter fugletype");

```
 try {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("fugler.txt"));
     List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
     while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     lines.add(sc.nextLine());
     }

     String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size]);

 }catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Comment: A bad, alternative way of saying: element in an array.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please try re-wording it.  Please clarify what "Arrayboxes" are and what "them" represents in the context of "I now want ot be able to search in them".

Comment: The question is very unclear - what is the result you need to get and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you don't need to put your lines into an array since you already have them in an `ArrayList`.

If you want to "search" lines and only print certain ones you could use [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
 try {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("fugler.txt"));
     List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
     while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         lines.add(sc.nextLine());
     }

     for (String line : lines) {
         if(line.contains("yourSearchString")) {
             System.out.println(line);
         }
     }

 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Comment: If I added a String search = input.next(); and then queried for search, which would define the "yourSearchString", would it be possible?

Comment: Nevermind that. It worked! You are my saviour saint! Thanks alot! :D
Though, it is kind of strange for me. It doesn't print the lines right away, until I input some other weird input and then it prints one line, and at next input another line which doesn't necessarily fullfill the requirements.

Comment: The method `contains` takes a `CharSequence` as an argument.  You can give it a `String` too.  The error is saying you are giving it an instance of `Scanner`.

Comment: Feel free to upvote any answers that were helpful, and accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: `input.next()` is waiting for your input!  If you don't want it to wait like that you are going to have to make a logic loop in your program.

Comment: Yes, but when I input a String, like crow, it doesnt print the lines which contains crow, until i input other weird stuff which makes it print all lines

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38055/discussion-between-makri-and-ubiquibacon)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other problems, if you want to have an array, you should replace this:

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

with this:

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

Your array that gets passed in is the array that will be populated by `toArray`, so it needs to be big enough to hold all the elements.

If you want to search for some value `line`, you can use the original `ArrayList<String>`:

```
// returns the index of the element, ie. its zero-based line number
int index = lines.indexOf(line);
```

To print them all, just loop through them all:

```
for(String l : lines) {
   System.out.println(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to put the lines in an array. You already have them in a list.

You could print them as they come in:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine() {
    String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    lines.add(currentLine);
}
```

Or, you could just print all the lines in your list:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```